# How do I pass multiple items selected from list to next view?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

In my view I ask the user 2 questions. Below each question, I have a list that allows the user to select multiple items.

1. How do I pass multiple items selected from list to next view?
2. How do I print the selections to debug console in Xcode?

Here is my Swift code in Xcode:

```
import SwiftUI

struct WelcomeView: View {
    
    @State var applications: [Application] = [Application(name: "Beer"),
                                              Application(name: "Hard Seltzer")]
    
    @State var legislations: [Legislation] = [Legislation(name: "Natural"),
                                              Legislation(name: "Natural and Artificial")]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Which applications are you interested in?")
                    .padding()
                List{
                    ForEach(0..<applications.count){ index in
                        HStack {
                            Button(action: {
                                applications[index].isSelected = applications[index].isSelected ? false : true
                            }) {
                                HStack{
                                    if applications[index].isSelected {
                                        Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                                            .animation(.easeIn)
                                    } else {
                                        Image(systemName: "circle")
                                            .foregroundColor(.primary)
                                            .animation(.easeOut)
                                    }
                                    Text(applications[index].name)
                                }
                            }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                        }
                    }
                }
                Text("Which legislations are you interested in?")
                    .padding()
                List{
                    ForEach(0..<legislations.count){ index in
                        HStack {
                            Button(action: {
                                legislations[index].isSelected = legislations[index].isSelected ? false : true
                            }) {
                                HStack{
                                    if legislations[index].isSelected {
                                        Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                                            .animation(.easeIn)
                                    } else {
                                        Image(systemName: "circle")
                                            .foregroundColor(.primary)
                                            .animation(.easeOut)
                                    }
                                    Text(legislations[index].name)
                                }
                            }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                        }
                    }
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: FlavorSearchView()) {
                    Text("Next")
                        .padding()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Application: Identifiable {
        var id = UUID()
        var name: String
        var isSelected: Bool = false
}

struct Legislation: Identifiable {
        var id = UUID()
        var name: String
        var isSelected: Bool = false
}

struct WelcomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        WelcomeView()
    }
}
```

Screen Preview:

[link to screen view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0ydp.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may pass the arrays as parameters to the next view like this:

```
NavigationLink(destination: FlavorSearchView(applications: applications, legislations: legislations))
```

And print the selection in the constructor of the view:

```
struct FlavorSearchView: View {
    
    init (applications: [Application], legislations: [Legislation]){
        self.applications = applications
        self.legislations = legislations
        
        print(applications)
        print(legislations)
    }
    
    let applications: [Application]
    let legislations: [Legislation]
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack{ }
    }
}
```

This approach will most certainly trigger the known bug in SwiftUI with auto popping. It’s discussed here:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/677333